# Installing kong on minikube in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, minikube, kong, kong-ingress

Following [this](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/deployment/minikube/) to install kong on minikube in ubuntu.
When I run:

> kubectl create -f
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/v2.10.0/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml

I get `kubectl` not found. So I added `minikube` at start.

> minikube kubectl create -f
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/v2.10.0/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml

It gives me: Error: unknown shorthand  flag: 'f' in -f. So what is correct way of doing it?

Comment: If your issue is resolved, Can you please post your resolution steps as an answer.

Comment: This is not how the site works. Answers in the answer section please. And post the updated command.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add the two signs `--` before create.

Comment: Please explain why, otherwise it just repeats what the op said

Comment: This *is* the OP's answer.